# What port should external users use to access my FTP server? Am I doing this right, even? Reality check..etc

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ftp, vsftpd

I am *very* new to Linux and computer science in general - please be patient with me.

I am attempting to create a read-only FTP server such that I can share some files in a manner as easy as possible for end users. I am in the preliminary stages of simply getting outside users (WAN)to be able to connect. I have had little luck. Here is my vsftpd.conf file:

anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=NO 
no_anon_password=YES
listen=YES
background=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=60000
pasv_max_port=60100
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.x.xx (my external IP)

I'm having people attempt to connect via FTP at external IP : 21 (port)

Does what I'm doing make sense?

My router is forwarded 21, 60000-60100, to my local IP of my server. Nobody can connect to my server - it just doesn't work, connection times out Thanks for the help.

I can access it through FTP on the LAN easily from another computer. The problem is outside users.

.

Comment: You should have people connecting to your external IP, not your router IP.

Comment: Google "What's my IP" and it will tell you your external IP address. You may also want to research what that is.

Comment: OK - I will edit my post. I meant to say external IP.

Comment: OK. You're also not really saying what the issue is.

Comment: Nobody can connect to my server - it just doesn't work, connection times out. I also am just trying to decide if I am going about this the correct way. IE - does this make sense at all?

Comment: You've done properly as far as I can tell, but you need to make sure you're not violating your ISP's AUP/ToS.  Port 21 my be blocked by tour ISP to prevent what your trying to do.

Comment: Timeout makes me think that you either are connecting to the wrong IP address or your ISP blocks incoming connections on 21. What is your ISP?

Comment: Time Warner Cable

Comment: If you don't really know what you're doing, it's probably a bad idea to try and give "outside users" access to your machine, because it's quite easy to rip severe security holes. Maybe a cloud storage service like Dropbox would be an easier alternative?

Comment: Fair enough. I hear you loud and clear.However, and respectfully, I would like to do this. I am trying my best here to be as cautious as possible. Furthermore, I'm not doing this on my main machine - It's on a dinky old laptop.

Comment: The "dinky old laptop" is still on your local network, and not the only machine there.  But anyway: In CS, it's always good practice to divide problems into smaller parts. Can you access the FTP server from the laptop itself? If not, look into why. Then, can you access the server from other machines in your LAN? If not, look into why, and so forth.

Comment: Crap. I can't believe I didn't mention that. I can access it through FTP on the LAN easily. It works, smooth as butter.

Comment: As mentioned above, check with TWC if they're blocking port 21. AFAIR, Comcast did that or still does, for example. Additionally, I'm not sure if it's correct to have the FTP server listen on your external IP. As far as I understood port forwarding, you forward all incoming data from "external:21" to "ip-in-lan:21". If then the FTP server listens on "external:21", it won't answer. But don't just take my word for it, because here my networking fu starts to get thin ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is way harder than I ever imagined. Maybe I'll consult a network guru IRL.

Comment: How about open the FTP at port 21 local, then use port forwarding in router, map it to port ex: 12345. Then user can connect to your ftp from outside using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345. As long as I know, ISPs are blocking the low ports and not high ports. Thats why you can try using high ports (until 65535).

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the port forwarding configuration as suggested by [x...](https://askubuntu.com/users/493453/x)

> (O)pen the FTP at port 21 local, then use port forwarding in router, map it to port ex: 12345. Then user can connect to your ftp from outside using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345.

This would circumvent any ISP troubles, but you would have to make sure that the port you choose is not used by any other service. There is a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) on commonly used ports.

Also you can troubleshoot the FTP server with a FTP client, such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), from your network and from a separate network such as the Library or a Cafe.

Even though it is read only, I still would **recommend** using a more secure way of distributing files, such as a dropbox, google drive, or by using SFTP.

---

*Good Luck! :)*